# ASP.NET MVC One Form, Two Buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, button, controller, action

I have a simple form based off a model called Visitor.  I'd like to have a search button by one of the id text fields so the user can click the button and have the page populate with visitor information: first name, last name, etc.  In Web Forms I would do something like this:

```
page_load(){
    person = businessManager.FindPersonById(Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text));
    txtFirstName.Text = person.FirstName;
    txtLastName.Text = person.LastName;
     ...
}
```

Prior to the search button, my view form called SignIn worked just fine; posted the data to the controller and did its thing:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignIn(Visitor visitor) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            visitorRepoistory.Add(visitor);
            visitorRepoistory.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        } else {
            return View(new VisitorFormViewModel(visitor));
        }
    }
```

But now that I have a search button placed on my view form, I'm totally lost.  I don't know how to wire the search button to the controller so I can: 1.) Look up the data and 2.) Return it back to the sign in form to populate the fields.  What are the steps I need to take to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444245/handling-2-buttons-submit-actions-in-a-single-view-form-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm

Comment: Problem is, I need to return back to the same page and populate the fields with the search results.  I think that's where I'm getting confused.

Comment: Do the search and return to the view passing to it your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been duplicated many times on SO

[Multiple forms in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822751/multiple-forms-in-asp-net-mvc)

But to answer your question you can have multiple forms on one page and have different Actions handle the submits.  That's what the link above outlines.

Specific to your case:

**View**

```
<% Html.BeginForm("Search", "<ControllerName>"); %>
    Your search controls here
<% Html.EndForm(); %>

<% Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "<ControllerName>"); %>
    Your signin controls here
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
{
   Do your search and return a view
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(Visitor visitor) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        visitorRepoistory.Add(visitor);
        visitorRepoistory.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("/");
    } else {
        return View(new VisitorFormViewModel(visitor));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a single form.  The search is just a way to look up the visitor information and populate the fields within the same form.

Comment: Right but you added a new button that does a submit, since you can't technically submit multiple actions on a single form you need to have a form for each action (e.g. Search and SignIn functionality) you wish to have.

Comment: You can submit multiple actions in a single form. See my answer.

Comment: If you are passing the same strongly typed data in both actions then yes you can have a single controller action for multiple submits (e.g. both submits use a Visitor object).  But if you are passing different data for each action then a strongly typed action won't work (e.g. Search takes 4 fields not related to visitor, and signin takes a visitor).  You would have to parse the entire form collection for both types of actions.  If that's the case multiple forms is a better way to go IMO