# Handling multi-forms in one View in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a problem with my page.  I have one view page and 2 forms in the same page.  I have seen and tried different approaches (like this one => [asp.net MVC 4 multiple post via different forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788806/asp-net-mvc-4-multiple-post-via-different-forms)) but I noticed a difference from my issue.

The problem is that I have a main form and another form which is a  shown by JQuery.  On initial display it is not shown but when they click a link, the second form is shown as a modal dialog box.  When I click the button in that box is does not seem to work.

I need your help on this please!

**Edited:**

Below are the codes I used in my application.

**.CSTHML Forms**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login2", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "loginForm" }))
{
    <a id="submitlink" href="#" class="button button-large">Sign In</a>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("TroubleSubmit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "troubleSubmitForm" }))
{
    <a id="troubleSubmitLink" href="#" class="button">OK</a>
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('a#submitlink').click(function () {
            $('#loginForm').submit();
        });

$('a#troubleSubmitlink').click(function () {
            $('#troubleSubmitForm').submit();
        });
```

The first form is working correctly.  However, when I click the 'OK' button of the second form nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: Could you post some code (View, Controller, JavaScript)? This will help us to analize and solve the issue!

Comment: I have updated the post to contain the codes.  I want the form to submit to different Actions in the Controller.  I have tried to have the same Action for both forms but it's still doesn't seem to work.  Maybe it's just me coz I'm new to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Both links submit `#loginForm`. Change the form selector for `troubleSubmitlink` handler.

Comment: Hi Jasen, sorry but it was an error on my part.  You see I have been testing around different scenarios to see where the post will go when I submit the second form.  I have corrected the code accordingly.  Thanks for pointing out by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchor tag's id has a capitol L on Link, while your jquery selector uses lower case. I believe selectors are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks bitwiser, the capital was the cause of the 2nd form not sumitting.

Answer (score 1):

To add to bitwiser's response.

If you do something like this with your JQuery

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href='#Submit']", function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).closest("form").submit()
});
```

Then you can do this with your html forms (note the hrefs, "#Submit"):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login2", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "loginForm" }))
{
    <a id="submitlink" href="#Submit" class="button button-large">Sign In</a>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("TroubleSubmit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "troubleSubmitForm" }))
{
    <a id="troubleSubmitLink" href="#Submit" class="button">OK</a>
}
```

With the jquery above, you don't need to setup individual click handlers for each link inside of a form.  You can just set the href to #Submit and the one global handler will take care of submitting.