# How to use multiple "save" button in single form in mvc4 c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am doing my project in mvc4 using c#

i have an edit form which consist of multiple "save" button.

```
<form method="post" action="Member/Edit">
<div id="personaldata">
     Classification<input type="text" name="Mem_Occ" value="@Model.Mem_Occ" />
     Birth Day<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Mem_DOB">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn"/>
</div>
<div id="contactdata">
    Email<input type="text" name="Mem_Email" value="@Model.Mem_Email"/>
    Mobile<input type="text" name="Mem_Mobile" value="@Model.Mem_Mobile" /><
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn" />
</div>
</form>
```

And my controller is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Model md)
    {
        try
        {                
            int edited = new Member().Edit(md.Mem_Occ,md.Mem_DOB,md.Mem_Email,md.Mem_Mobile);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Actually my need is when i **click on the particular save button, only that part data is edited and saved in the database** (all data is contained in the same table.). How it possible. please help me.

Comment: Use multiple forms with different post method

Comment: @Nilesh: you mean different controller actions?

Comment: yes you can use different controller action or same action

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788806/asp-net-mvc-4-multiple-post-via-different-forms

Comment: In html, a form can only have one submit button.  If you need multiple submits, you need multiple forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<form method="post" action="YOUR ACTION1">
<div id="personaldata">
     Classification<input type="text" name="Mem_Occ" value="@Model.Mem_Occ" />
     Birth Day<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Mem_DOB">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn"/>
</div>
</form>


<form method="post" action="YOUR ACTION2">
<div id="contactdata">
    Email<input type="text" name="Mem_Email" value="@Model.Mem_Email"/>
    Mobile<input type="text" name="Mem_Mobile" value="@Model.Mem_Mobile" /><
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn" />
</div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action1(Model md)
{

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action2(Model md)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use name and value attribute to filter.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Model md, string submit)
{
    if (submit == "Save")
    {
        // Code for function 1
    }
    else if (submit == "Submit")
    {
        // code for function 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ActionNameSelector and custom ActionMethodSelector. Check this codeproject article to start up with the concepts: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291433/Custom-Action-Method-Selector-in-MVC

or

To clear the basic concept of ActionNameSelector and ActionMethodSelector you can check this link: http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2014/02/aspnet-mvc-actionnameselector-and.html
and this: http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2014/02/aspnet-mvc-actionnameselector-and_2.html